# mouseenter / mouseleave solution that doesn't trigger when mouse enters the smaller second element positioned in the first element

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

Here is a simple html+css+js code

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  console.log('Mouse entered the div');
});

myDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  console.log('Unfortunately this message happens when we enter the smaller div');
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
#smaller {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  <div id="smaller">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue here is mouseleave triggers when the mouse appears above the second element. Any nice and simple solution to avoid that? Tried another events. No luck.

P.S. JS solution is preferable. CSS hover is not the way to go for my case.
The important note - **divs are on the same level (the second div is not a child of the first div).**

Comment: Of course it triggers since you left the OTHER div with the events attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `relatedTarget` and a control flag to check if you were entering the smaller div(s).

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var inSmall = false;

myDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  if (inSmall) {
    inSmall = false;
    return;
  }
  console.log('Mouse entered the div');
});
myDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget.id === 'smaller') {
    inSmall = true;
    return;
  }
  console.log('Unfortunately this message happens when we enter the smaller div');
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

#smaller {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  <div id="smaller">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want `mouseenter` to trigger again when entering from the smaller div, you can remove the control flag.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  console.log('Mouse entered the div');
});
myDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  if (e.relatedTarget.id === 'smaller') return;
  console.log('Unfortunately this message happens when we enter the smaller div');
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

#smaller {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  <div id="smaller">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. This is the solution that exactly mets my needs. Nice, perfect, thanks a lot! Accepting this answer as a best one for my needs. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the HTML structure as it is you can put a `pointer-events: none;` on the smaller element.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  console.log('Mouse entered the div');
});

myDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  console.log('Unfortunately this message happens when we enter the smaller div');
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

#smaller {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  <div id="smaller">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good solution perhaps; even though the OP said JS events only and may have some reasoning, this is a nice solution.

Comment: Nice solution, yes, unfortunately the 3rd party code in my case makes some js actions over #smaller piece. pointer-events: none; breaks that functionality the 3rd party code does but I don't control. Another answer ideally met my case - exactly to avoid the mouseleave event to happen when we enter the #smaller.

Answer (score 1):

### Nest the `#smaller` `div` inside of the `#myDiv` `div` to fix the issue.

Place the `#smaller` `div` inside of the `#myDiv`. This counts the smaller div as part of the `#myDiv` `div` and doesn't trigger your `mouseleave` event listener. This shouldn't mess with your structure since the `#smaller` `div` is already utilizing `position: absolute;`.

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  console.log('Mouse entered the div');
});

myDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  console.log('Unfortunately this message happens when we enter the smaller div');
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
#smaller {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="myDiv"><div id="smaller"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't even notice that they did that.

Comment: Unfortunately, divs supposed to be at the same level, sorry I didn't notice that.

Comment: Is there a reason the divs have to be on the same level?

Comment: @NickFriesen, unfortunately yes. The code is significantly simplified.

Comment: If you needed to, you could identify the `#smaller` div and append it inside of the `#myDiv` using JavaScript. Is this a solution which could work for you? Since you are utilizing `position: absolute;`, my point still stands that making the `#smaller` div a child of your `#myDiv` `div` is still a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe it just put the event on the containing element and you are good to go.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.div-container');

container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  console.log('Mouse entered the div');
});

container.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  console.log('Unfortunately this message happens when we enter the smaller div');
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

#smaller {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-container">
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
  <div id="smaller">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice soluion, thank you very much. In my case (but I didn't mention that) there were some more elements inside div-container other than myDiv and smaller, that didn't allow me to implement this solution. But based on what I described above - yes, it looks perfect. Thank you very much.